# Trying to concatenate 11 seconds of black video onto the end of a 5 min video. Getting non-monotonous DTS in output stream error

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I have a video shot from my smartphone that is 3840x2160@57.74. Originally, it was exactly 5 minutes long. I replaced the audio with a music file that is 5 minutes and 11 seconds using `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 output.mp4` I expected 11 seconds of black at the end, but instead the video output freezes on the last frame for 11 seconds. There's definitely something funky going on because when I try to upload to youtube, it only sees the first 5 minutes. The last 10 seconds of audio get dropped.

I tried making a second black clip with  `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=uhd2160:r=57.74 -t 11 -pix_fmt yuv420p blk2.mp4`. When I try to concat the two files with `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy teacup6.mp4` I get a huge list of errors such as `[mp4 @ 00000166fda994c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 27002920, current: 3728954; changing to 27002921. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.` for what appears to be about 11 seconds worth of frames, so basically the entire 11 second black clip. When I play it in VLC it goes black, but I suspect it's not actually processing/playing 11 seconds of good black video because if I click along the track timeline, visual glitches start happening in the canvas.

Here is what ffmpeg tells me about my inputs and outputs as far as framerate, pixel format, etc.

`[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000239e6cb2880] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Input #0, concat, from 'list.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: -0.023021, bitrate: 72244 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 3840x2160, 71994 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 57.74 fps, 59 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 250 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, mp4, to 'teacup5.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.102
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 71994 kb/s, 57.74 fps, 59 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 250 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help`

alternatively, I tried to make a black 3840x2160 png file and create an 11 second slideshow. It didn't turn out any better. I tried a single image for 11 seconds @ 57.74fps, I also tried a looping slideshow of that one image, looping on every single frame, at 57.74 fps. I should note that wether a slideshow or a color generator, the filesize for the 11 seconds of black comes out to about 160KB. Strangely small in my opinion, but I was chalking it up to a good compression algorithm.

I tried to do this in Da Vinci Resolve 16.1 instead and the video wouldn't play. I also couldn't find a way to maintain the same unusual 57.74 framerate with the free version, so it was undesirable anyway. I tried to re-process using Handbrake, but it threw an error. The output of the Handbrake processed video file also gets stuck on the last frame of the video, instead of going to black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [tpad filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tpad) is the easiest method:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:v]tpad=stop=-1[v]" -map "[v]" -map 1:a -c:a copy -shortest output.mp4
```

See the link above for additional options such as how to change the color of the blank frames or to repeat the last frame instead of making a solid color.

Comment: Thank you llogan for your help. I got a good enough video that I'm happy with it thanks to you. a couple things about your tpad method...

1. `Shortest` wouldn't work. ffmpeg gave an error `Unable to find a suitable output format for 'shortest' shortest: Invalid argument` so I had to take it out and monitor the encode, then press q when it was long enough.

2. Because of `-c:a`, it re-encoded the video. The bitrate went way down and my framerate changed to 59.00. Because of my PC's hardware, processing time went from 2 min for a direct copy to 50 min for the re-encode.

Comment: @TidusWulf Shouldn't be getting that `Invalid argument` error. Can you show the command you tried?